# Dynamically include dagger2 modules

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have dagger component `MainComponent`, which is dependent on another module: `LocalModule` or `PrdModule`. I would like to dynamically include one of the modules based on some flag. Quick example:

In code it looks like this:

```
@Component(modules = [LocalModule::class])
interface MainComponent
```

However, if I'm building my app for customer, then I must change it manually to:

```
@Component(modules = [PrdModule::class])
interface MainComponent
```

What I would like to have is something like this:

```
@Component(modules = [if(someFlag) {LocalModule::class} else {PrdModule::class}])
interface MainComponent
```

It'd be nice if I could set this flag in gradle's build options.

Comment: Have you considered using different [product favors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors) (with different [source sets](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#sourcesets))?

Comment: No, I'll take a look, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks jsamol, different source sets solved my problem. It was exactly what I was looking for!